Lightning strike uploads all the internet's info to a teenager?
I remember watching a film some 20 years ago (film itself may easily be older but most likely 90s-based) where a teenager using a computer at school during a storm. A lightning bolt hits the school and somehow turns him into a genius (not sure they specifically references the internet back then).
The rest of the film is kind of a blur but I do vaguely recall him being chased and losing his powers towards the end. If I'm not mistaken the villains in the film pass on some sort of virus through a phone call to the guy. All this happens around the point where the main protagonist is taking part in a TV show of some sort (and I believe he wins despite not having this widespread knowledge anymore). Any ideas?

The Computer Wore Tennis Shoes (1995)
I remember this movie very well. Used to watch it a lot in TV.

By accident, the content of a computer encyclopedia is transferred into the brain of Dexter Riley, a less than average college boy. Because of his newly acquired knowledge he competes in a quiz show between various universities, where he sweeps all the points. A wiz kid from another university finds out about his cheated wisdom and does everything to discredit Dexter.

This movie was actually based on another one from the 60s who received a much more positive review.


Sounds like that's the one! Thanks! :)
